# Are we more disciplined here than at StackOverflow? Or Are we a bit ignorant here when flagging comments?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

Whenever I get to access internet, I spend quite a lot of time on The Great Outdoors at StackExchange. (You bet, even more than I do on Facebook/Twitter/blogger).
And, I love going through old answered/unanswered questions. Over the period of time I have developed this habit to flag whatever is unnecessary, irrelevant and obsolete.
And, that has earned me a [Deputy Badge](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/badges/70/deputy). The thing that strikes me the most is, that I am the only user with that badge.

So, I wonder, are we(users) more disciplined here than at StackOverflow when its about posting comments? Or Are we a bit ignorant here when its about flagging comments?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Neither.

All normal betas go through a growth phase, where someone has to be the first one to gain each badge. We are still a small site, with only two 10k'ers, and only four of us over 5k, so consider this early days. StackOverflow is most definitely not a good comparison to this site. The big-3 sites are massive and have their own quirks.

Congratulations on getting there first - and I hope to see others soon, as Deputy is a very useful badge, helping guide the community.