# Need to start looking at flagging?

Tags: discussion, flagging

As we all can see, we've got new users who are looking active. Signs are good and vivid with good questions being asked by many new as well as few *long-time-here* users. That said, the few of the posts are getting many of the comments which would get deleted as *"being chatty"* on other SE sites.

In the same context I had asked a question when I got my first Deputy badge here at TGO.
[Are we more disciplined here than at StackOverflow? Or Are we a bit ignorant here when flagging comments?](https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/q/502/2303)

I feel that getting user involved in communications (which *sometimes* get a bit chatty) is good for us as of now.

Say for an example, a new user will love to get a "Good one mate, +1 for xyz point in the answer", and would rather *may* get inspired to try and answer/question more, ultimately getting the activity on this site. Even I many a times appreciate a good question by a comment, and do the same for an answer by saying "Good, +1 for this and that..", which I believe is fine (as of now), rather than having a cut-throat approach like restraining myself from putting "a +1 comment" it being "too chatty".

Or should we start flagging such comments and refrain ourselves from making such comments, so the clean-up wouldn't take long?

Comment: There are some definite comments which are too chatty and most aren't even '+1' comments, those should be dealt with first, and a lot of '+1' comments come with additional information anyway.

Comment: @Ara: I Agree. But few of the comments do not anything valuable to the answer. I think we should get rid of those.

Comment: the best way to start discouraging them is not to post them ourselves on new questions, as you said, but not all +1 questions are bad, so shouldn't be writing them all off because a post has '+1' at the start.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I tend to handle new users differently than experienced ones.  Even if they have a bad question/answer/comment, I will lean towards trying to nudge them in the right direction.  We can't expect people to read a treatise on proper form and totally understand the spirit of the boards before their first post.

And frankly, I don't want to be SO.  Their policies have become stifling and long since overcame all else.  TGO is about helping share the knowledge need to enjoy the real great outdoors.  We aren't doing that if we care so much about SO etiquette that we forget why we started the board.  I like the SE engine, but the SO culture I could do without.

META is where we ask questions about TGO, but what we often forget is that "proper SE etiquette" is entirely META to most of our visitors.  Before we demand they follow a bunch of rules, we have to show them that participation is worth their time and effort.

"Remember: we're all here to learn, so be friendly and helpful!" -- From our tour page.

Comment: +1 ;) I'd just like to add in reference to so many things discussed on TGO the bottom line is usually 'Lead by example', if the community does what is acceptable and avoids that which is not, it will be clearer for new users as well.

Comment: +1 I totally second that